# Strange copy of a Stack Overflow question on w3facility.info

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

While googling for an answer to a problem I found two pages with exactly the same content, one of those is Stack Overflow. I'm quite sure the clone page is not mainained by Stack Exchange.

Does anyone know more about this kind of clone pages? It has a small link to the original page, but is that enough to be legal?

- The Original: [Run native binary CGI on lighttpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862908/run-native-binary-cgi-on-lighttpd)
- The clone: http://w3facility.info/question/run-native-binary-cgi-on-lighttpd/

Comment: Everything on SE sites is licensed as CC-By-SA... so as long as they meet the attribution requirements, it is legal.  I *think* this looks legit.  They link back to the original question, link back to the original authors profile page, and identify the content as from Stack Exchange.

Comment: @psubsee2003 The author link doesn't go to the right place.

Comment: From their [About Us](http://w3facility.info/about-us/) page: "We have build this facility over the Stack Exchange sql dump as well as Yahoo Answers feed to populate these questions archive so that users may get maximum relevant answers to all their questions in one place." Because Google doesn't provide that service, apparently.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I stand corrected, I missed the it didn't link here.

Comment: @BilltheLizard there is actually a "Source Link: Stack Exchange" right at the very top of the question, shows you where it came from and it links back to the original question. They probably wanna do something kool with authors like make an aggregated page for all networks for them but they just havent yet or whatever

Comment: Weird - why would they build a site like that if it's not paid by advertisements? It's up since 2012

Comment: What is also interesting is that he is spidering ALL SE sites: http://w3facility.info/questions/category/webmasters-2/

Comment: Apparently, they are trying to launch a new social network, pardon Q&A service. Currently looking for the audience they do not have. To compare, Reddit faked users in the beginning.

Comment: Any relation to w3schools?

Comment: @muistooshort, I wouldn't be surprised -- w3schools doesn't have a lot of moral fiber either, given their penchant for using a name that suggests a relationship with the W3C (which they don't have) and their very lax attitude re: correcting inaccuracies in their content.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am not trying to tell that w3school is cool, but how is their name suggest relationship to w3c? This is just a domain which was available and easy to remember. Following your logic, does javascriptweekly.com a bad place simply because they suggest relationship with javascript?

Comment: @SalvadorDali "javascript" isn't an international community that develops standards. By using w3schools it suggests that they are in some way affiliated (which they are not) to this international community that sets standards for development, thereby making it sound official to newbies. javascript weekly on the other hand suggests that the website is associated with javascript, which is correct and intended. javascript is a language, not a standards community. apples & oranges.

Comment: @KevinB: Yes. A better analogy would be if they made a site called ECMAschool for JS coding, or WG14school for C coding, etc. - but I think W3schools is even worse in thast W3C is widely recognized by their audience, whereas ECMA and WG14 are not so much.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on the meta site for all of the Stack Exchange network, in particular it is a cross-duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: A lot of people that don't know any better seem to think that w3schools is some sort of official branch of W3C. That would suggest to me that the name is misleading.

Comment: W3 is short for WWW, so W3C is the World Wide Web Consortium, an international standards body.  W3SCHOOLS would apparently be a site that wants to teach about the WWW, and it's not called `w3Cschools`.  I've never thought they were associated and I really don't get all the hate.  Yes there are many better sites out there now, but they really aren't that bad especially for people new to web development.  They were the first site I found that had live demos that let you play with the code to see the effects in your browser, long before sites like jsfiddle and plunker were around.

Comment: I don't find w3schools useful and am annoyed every time I see it in Google simply because one of its unrelated pages has a high enough rank from noob clicks.  With that said however, it does not have w3c anywhere in the name.  Somebody who sees w3c in the name needs to see an optometrist fast or try reading slower.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I have heard many people thinking it was associated with W3C. To a non attentive user the difference between w3cschools and w3schools is probably none.

Comment: Here is another page with the same issue: http://unix.aspcode.net/view/63539508700411522934904/using-debuild-to-build-shared-libraries-deb . I only saw it because google showed me links to two different pages with the same content

Comment: @JasonGoemaat, So why don't we register W3C.is, W3C.app, W3C.me, after naming our website as World Wide Web Cute and hide a message *"not affiliated with World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)"* in a page the visitor cannot find? Yes, W3 is short for WWW,  but **[misrepresentation](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=misrepresentation) is misrepresentation**. It's the [intention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intention_%28criminal_law%29) we're looking at.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The link to the question author is broken, but the answer author is even worse: no link and no name.  That's a clear violation of the content license.

(One reason for requiring a direct link to the poster profile is to provide correct attribution even if the poster's screen name has changed)

[image]

Report it via the usual procedure: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

Comment: Reusing the SO content under the CC terms also requires stating that the content is licensed under those terms. This site is failing to do that - it makes no mention of CC, and just has a "© 2012 by w3facility
" footer.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: seems they have updated their footer, as well as the links to the profiles

Comment: Also besides w3facility.info, w3facility. **org**

Comment: @Pacerier: You can comment here or not, but do use the reporting procedure I linked in my answer.